# Usage ffmpeg with Qt on mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, qt, ffmpeg, clang

I'm trying to build some app on Mac OS X 10.8.5.

I'm using Qt 5.1.1 (Clang 3.1, 64 bit) and Qt Creator 2.8.1

ffmpeg the latest from the git repos.

ffmpeg was builded successfully with following config

```
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-      libaacplus --enable-libass --enable-libcelt --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-openssl --enable-libopus --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --disable-static --cc=clang --arch=x86_64 --enable-libxvid --prefix=/Users/ad/dev/ffmpeg/build
```

But when i'm trying to build application int Qt i'm receving a lot of errors, smth like:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_BN_CTX_free", referenced from:
  _dh_is_valid_public_key in libavformat.a(rtmpdh.o)
"_BN_CTX_new", referenced from:
  _dh_is_valid_public_key in libavformat.a(rtmpdh.o)
"_BN_bin2bn", referenced from:
  _ff_dh_compute_shared_secret_key in libavformat.a(rtmpdh.o)
etc...
```

IMHO i'm facing the problem with linking ffmpeg. Because when i builded it i used clang compiler. But Qt used clang++ compiler.
I tried to rebuild ffmpeg with flag

```
--cc=clang++
```

instead of

```
--cc=clang
```

in my first config.
But then i receiving error:

```
ERROR: libaacplus >= 2.0.0 not found
```

But libaacplus presented in my enviroment.

Could anyone say me, please, how can i decide this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems same issue to this, although different library,

[Qt5.1/Qt5.2 + Mac OS 10.9 (Mavericks) + XCode 5.0.2, Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342896/solved-qt5-1-qt5-2-mac-os-10-9-mavericks-xcode-5-0-2-undefined-symbols)

You may have to change the number (10.9 in the post) to different setting (maybe 10.8, depending on your XCode SDKs but not Mac OS version)