# How to install OpenCV lib under OS X Mavericks and make it work with Code::Blocks

Tags: macos, opencv, installation, osx-mavericks, codeblocks

I would like to use OpenCV library with Code::Blocks.

I have already installed OpenCV with the following command line :

> sudo port install opencv

The above command created multiple opencv folders in /opt/local/include/, /opt/local/var/macports/software/, /opt/local/var/macports/sources/ and /opt/local/share/.

What should I do now to make it work with Code::Blocks ?

[EDIT 24.06]

Thanks to cyriel, I have managed to install OpenCV and make it work with QT Creator.

To install Homebrew and OpenCV just type the following command lines :

> ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
>
> brew doctor
>
> brew tap homebrew/science
>
> brew install opencv

Then, set cyriel's project settings and try to compile and execute following source code :

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat image;
    image = imread("/image-path/image-filename.image-format", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    if(! image.data )
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "Display window", image );
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

and it works just fine !

**Regarding Code::Blocks**

In Build options > Linker Settings, I have linked all the *.a and *.dylib files that are in the /usr/include/lib/ folder.

In Build options > Search directories > Compiler, I have added /usr/local/lib, /usr/local/include/opencv and /usr/local/include folders

In Build options > Search directories > Linker, I have added /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/include/opencv

I am not familiar with external libraries so I m not really sure if my configuration is correct but it doesn't seem to compile correctly.

> -------------- Run: Debug in ImgDownsampling-V1 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------
>
> Checking for existence:
> /Users/Universe/Desktop/Coding/ImgDownsampling-V1/bin/Debug/ImgDownsampling-V1
> Executing: osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"' -e 'activate' -e 'do
> script "/Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner
> DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:.:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/include/opencv
> /Users/Universe/Desktop/Coding/ImgDownsampling-V1/bin/Debug/ImgDownsampling-V1
> "' -e 'end tell'  (in
> /Users/Universe/Desktop/Coding/ImgDownsampling-V1/.)

Terminal doesn't show up...

[EDIT 24.06]

I have tried to change settings and managed to make it work !

Same Code::Blocks configuration as before except that I have cleared all the folders in Build options > Search directories > Linker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience in using `Code::Blocks` neither `port` app, but i've sucesfully managed to install OpenCV using `brew`(it's **GREAT!**) on Mavericks to work with Qt Creator.
First you need to install OpenCV - `brew install opencv`. If you want to install it with additional options, just use `brew options opencv`. Install some version of Qt and Qt Creator (i'm using Qt 4.5, because it's easy to integrate it with OpenCV) and in project settings set:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.9

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib

LIBS += \
    -lopencv_calib3d \
    -lopencv_contrib \
    -lopencv_core \
    -lopencv_flann \
    -lopencv_gpu \
    -lopencv_highgui \
    -lopencv_imgproc \
    -lopencv_legacy \
    -lopencv_ml \
    -lopencv_objdetect \
    -lopencv_ocl \
    -lopencv_photo \
    -lopencv_stitching \
    -lopencv_superres \
    -lopencv_ts \
    -lopencv_video \
    -lopencv_videostab
    -lopencv_nonfree

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv \
                   /usr/include/opencv \
                /usr/local/include 
DEPENDPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv/include
```

Config is quite obvious, except this line - `QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.9`. If you want to know why you need to use it, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811858/opencv-mac-os-x-qt-creator-strange-linking-bug/21830748#21830748%20this%20topic).
Configuring Code::Blocks should be quite similar, if you will have any problem try starting with Qt and then moving to Code::Blocks.