# How to Link OpenCV 2.4.9 & Qt Creator in MacOS X

Tags: macos, qt, opencv

I have installed OpenCV using Homebrew in Mac OS Mavericks and QT Creator from the website.

I am trying to test OpenCV & QT Creator using a simple program from the internet, but I am ending up with some errors.

I donno wats going wrong.... I am new to Opencv and QT ... Your Help is much appreciated..

Below are my project details. Guide me for my first ever OpenCV & QT with Mac OS X Program.....

Thx.

--- Untitled.pro File ---

```
QT += core   
QT -= gui
TARGET = untitled1
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
LIBS += -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib \
-lopencv_highgui \
-lopencv_imgproc \
-lopencv_core \
-lopencv_features2d \
-lopencv_calib3d \
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/include \
```

---

--- Source File - main.cpp ---

```
include opencv2/core/core.hpp
include opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp
include iostream
include opencv/cv.h
using namespace cv;

int main()   
{ 
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    cv::Mat mat;

    mat = cv::imread("Unknown.JPEG");

    cvNamedWindow("hello");

    cv::imshow("hello",mat);
    cvWaitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

---

--- The Compile Output with Errors ---

> 14:30:57: Running steps for project untitled... 14:30:57: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step. 14:30:57: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" /Users/Macs/Qt/5.3.1/bin/qmake -spec macx-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=x86_64 -o Makefile ../untitled/untitled.pro /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/g++ -headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -o untitled main.o -F/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.3.1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -framework QtCore Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "cv::imread(std::string const&, int)", referenced from: _main in main.o "cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from: _main in main.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) make: * [untitled] Error 1 14:30:57: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2. Error while building/deploying project untitled (kit: Desktop) When executing step "Make" 14:30:57: Elapsed time: 00:00.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer by myself, but before post it I did a search and found that an answer was already posted here by [cyriel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811858/opencv-mac-os-x-qt-creator-strange-linking-bug).
Anyway the answer is to insert in your .pro file:

`QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.9`

There is also another correct answer by maythe4thbewithu in [maythe4thbewithu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342896/qt5-1-qt5-2-mac-os-10-9-mavericks-xcode-5-0-2-undefined-symbols-for-archi?lq=1%20with%20the%20explanation)